# readr::read_delim results in different column names on mac and windows

Tags: r, readr

I received a (hopeless) excel worksheet from a colleague that includes several identical column names. I import using reader::read_delim after having saved the sheet as csv. However, the duplicate variables are not identical when I import on mac and windows-i.e. returning x & x_1 and x...16 & x...28 respectively on the two systems. Any idea how this can remedied without resorting to renaming in excel before saving?

```
a <- readr::read_delim("_190422.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, 
                       locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"),
                       col_types = cols(x = col_date(format = "%d.%m.%Y"), 
                                        y = col_date(format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
                                        'z_date' = col_date(format = "%d.%m.%Y")), 
                       na = "NA", 
                       trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `name_repair = "unique"` argument of `read_delim`

Comment: Is there a reason you're exporting to csv before importing rather than using `readxl`?

Comment: I guess the magic happens in name_repair, but why reader::read_delim returns different variable names on mac and windows is obscure to me.